# SharePoint Lists.asmx UpdateListItems SET Field1=NewValue WHERE Field1=OldValue (filter by to be updated field)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, list, service

What I would like to do seems simple, I have an application that interacts with some SharePoint (MOSS 2007) lists via SharePoint Services. In one service call I'd like to update one or more list items. The problem is I want to only update those items where the field to be updated equals and old value. My thought was to use the Lists.UpdateListItems and filter then update but I haven't been able to find the syntax for it.

In pseudo: Update the [Name] to "NewName" of all items in [ListA] where [Name] = "OldName"

One solution I would like to avoid: Get ID of all ListItems where Name="OldName" and iterate through them making a separate service call for each one to update Name="NewName".

I cannot reference the Microsoft.SharePoint assemblies so ideally this is in one service call.

Comment: What is the problem with getting the ID and iterating?  Is it a performance issue?

Comment: Yes, i'd rather not have to hit the server for each record found, i was hoping to hit it in one request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make **2 calls**, one to retrieve the matching items and one to do the update(s).

This can be fairly involved so I have written a blog post (including the necessary code) about it here: http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2011/02/11/batch-updates-with-sharepoint-2007-services/

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works for me and your post was very helpful. Wish SharePoint services provided a way to do this in one service call but for now this is functional.